# Do not propagate conversation manually +CDI +JS2 +WELD

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I have a xhtml with a form with a backing bean running in ConversationScoped.

I want create a FORM that submits and do not propagate the conversation (CID).

On the generated html the CID appears in the action on the form tag:

```
<form id="forme" name="form_nova_senha" method="post" action="/plma/index.xhtml?cid=1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found reading source of WeldPhaseListener

```
   public static String getConversationId(FacesContext facesContext, ConversationContext conversationContext) {
        Map<String, String> map = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        if (map.containsKey(NO_CID))
            return null; // ignore cid; WELD-919

        String cidName = conversationContext.getParameterName();
        String cid = map.get(cidName);
        log.trace(FOUND_CONVERSATION_FROM_REQUEST, cid);
        return cid;
    }
```

Just need to put the nocid paramenter on request.